# Arcgis Map : PictureMarkerSymbol couldnt show marker and gives error

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis, esri

I just created picture symbol , but when i implement the pictureMarkerSymbol , it still gives me error. i dont know what went wrong but this is the codes i am using.

This line was in red 
"http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Basic/RedStickpin.png");
It says to " Surround with try and catch" 
eventhough i trie try and catch , it still does give me error. :(

anybody know how to trouble shoot this?

Thank you in advance

```
//------if latitutde and longitude is not equal / loop 
    if (eve_lat_default !=0 && eve_longi_default !=0) {
graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

//--point latlong on location   
Point latlong = new Point(eve_longi_default, eve_lat_default);

//--Convert Spatial reference from 4326(WorldMap) to 3414(ONE MAP)
final Point point = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(latlong, SpatialReference.create(4326),      //WORLDMAP 
                                                                                                                            //CONVERT TO
                                                                                    SpatialReference.create(3414));     //ONEMAP



//Picture Symbol (PIN USING JSON URL FROM ESRI Website)
PictureMarkerSymbol pms = new PictureMarkerSymbol(
                                "http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Basic/RedStickpin.png");
pms.setAngle(0f);
pms.setOffsetX(0f);
pms.setOffsetY(12f);


//add graphic layer
GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();


graphicsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(new Point(12, 34), pms));

//add symbol to mapview
mMapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);

mMapView.zoomToResolution(point,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `PictureMarkerSymbol` constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/symbol/PictureMarkerSymbol.html#PictureMarkerSymbol%28java.lang.String%29) throws both `IOException` and `MalformedURLException`. `MalformedURLException` extends `IOException`, so catching IOException is good enough:

```
try {
    PictureMarkerSymbol pms = new PictureMarkerSymbol(
        "http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Basic/RedStickpin.png");
    pms.setAngle(0f);
    pms.setOffsetX(0f);
    pms.setOffsetY(12f);
    GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    mMapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);
    graphicsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(new Point(12, 34), pms));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    //The URL was no good; handle the error
}
```

That will compile.

Comment: I just want click on PictureMarkerSymbol so that address popup can be shown